# autocomplete error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a django project and want to autocomplete words in an input text box.

This is text box:

```
<input type="text" id="keyword_search" class="form-control basicAutoComplete" name="city_district" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

This is cdn of bootstrap and jquery:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap.min-css" href="{% static 'vira_app/wp/css/bootstrap.min-3.7.0.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-theme.min-css" href="{% static 'vira_app/wp/css/bootstrap-theme.min-3.7.0.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/xcash/bootstrap-autocomplete@v2.3.7/dist/latest/bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vira_app/wp/js/jquery.min-3.5.1.js' %}" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vira_app/wp/js/jquery-migrate.min-3.3.2.js' %}" id="jquery-migrate-js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vira_app/wp/js/modernizr.custom.62456-3.7.0.js' %}" id="modernizr.custom.62456-js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vira_app/wp/js/v4-shims.min-3.1.4.js' %}" id="font-awesome-4-shim-js"></script>
</head>
```

And it is script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{{ cities_json | escapejs }}');
        $('.basicAutoComplete').autoComplete({
            resolverSettings: {
                url: jsonObject
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

At first I face this error:

> bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'VERSION' of undefined ... at u.getBootstrapVersion (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ...
> at u.init (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at new u (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at HTMLInputElement. (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370) ... at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137) ... at jQuery.fn.init.n.fn. [as autoComplete] (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at HTMLDocument. ((index):659) ... at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232) ... at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)

And after commenting `jquery-ui.js`, it's solved. But now I have this errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined ... at u.getBootstrapVersion (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at u.init (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at new u (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at HTMLInputElement. (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370) ... at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137) ... at jQuery.fn.init.n.fn. [as autoComplete] (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1) ... at HTMLDocument. ((index):659) ... at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232) ...
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)

And this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

And also!

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isMouseOver' of undefined

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: You're including two versions of jQuery, for starters. Don't use jQuery UI and bootstrap. Pick a single frontend framework and stick to it.

Comment: @ChrisG as I said, jQueryUI is now comment and there is three last errors

Comment: You need to also remove `jquery-1.12.4.js`

Comment: @ChrisG Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at o (bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1
    at bootstrap-autocomplete.min.js:1

Comment: You need to include the jQuery script before the bootstrap script

Comment: @ChrisG not working

Comment: "not working" is a useless problem description. What is your actual script order? It needs to be 1. jQuery 2. bootstrap 3. bootstrap autocomplete (and nothing else)

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is text, and after parsing, the result is an object. Plus, `url:` expects the backend URL to where Django delivers a list of matches in a specific format, based on the `q=...` parameter (which contains the contents of the text field)